# VS Code on Windows: install python packages to the default directory

Tags: installation, pip, visual-studio-code

When i install extensions like pylint through the VSCode GUI (it tells me that it needs some package and asks me if i want to install it), it installs them to ...

`C:/Users/me/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/...`

by doing

`python -m pip install -U <package> --user`

How can i make VS Code install them to the default directory by doing

`python -m pip install <package>`

?

I prefer having everything in one folder.

(I know how to do this from a command line but im curious where this setting resides in VSCode)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself, the setting is:`python.globalModuleInstallation`.